# how to save visual studio settings file permanently

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mstest, appdomain, settings.settings

**Project A** having a mstest (ui test) - has a settings file `AppSettings.Settings` with public access

**Project B** (A VS Addin) which reference A

*AppSettings*

```
Key1 = DefaultVal1
Key2 = DefaultVal2
```

*I am doing this in Project B*

```
ProjectA.Properties.AppSettings.Default.Key1 = Value1;
ProjectA.Properties.AppSettings.Default.Save();
```

**Problem:** The mstest in ProjA triggered by ProjB, doesn't see the changes in settings file made by project B. It only sees the default values present in settings file.

Is there anyway I can save the changes in settings file permanently?

**EDIT :** I found that Project A runs in a different AppdDomain than Project B. So my question now is how can I persists values of AppSettings.Settings across different AppDomains.

Answer (score 0):

here it explains how you can export and or import settings in vs, 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1x6229t8(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1x6229t8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
I hope it was usefull ^^ and the thing your were looking for

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the two AppDomains have two separate cached copies of the settings. `Save()` persists them on disk, so now you need Project A to refresh its copy.

Have you tried calling [`Reload()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the settings object from a function within Project A?